# Not changing Assembly Version for dll a problem in WP7?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, dll

I have a project for one dll I use in a wp7 game. After changing the dll code and overriding the original dll from the game it had some problems running correctly. Either the emulator started and the program immediately was exiting or it was using still the old dll. Removing the reference to add it again, rebuilding the project or deinstalling it from the emulator didn't help always. What worked was changing the AssemblyVersion in the dll project.

My question is now if I change the dll and forget to adjust the AssemblyVersion could this lead to problems when publishing? 
Is there any sharing on the WP7 of dll files between different apps/games or after reinstalling an app/game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, hitting refresh on your solution after you've updated a DLL should force the solution to update all the references and your application should no longer be linked to an old version of a DLL file.

As far as the sharing, there is no sharing of DLLs among the different applications which a user installs on their phone and the applications should always be checked my Microsoft prior to submission into the Marketplace to make sure that they are installed and uninstalled correctly. If there is a problem then the application won't pass the submission and will not be published into the Marketplace.